# Trying to combine jquery clone, appendTo

Tags: jquery

```
$('.reply').click(function () {

                var replybox = $(".replybox").clone().show();
                $(replybox).appendTo(this,parent('.post'));

        });
```

What I'm trying to do:

1. Clone .replybox (display:none;) then make it visible
2. Put inside $(this).parent('.post')
3. Ideally make .replybox show/hide on .reply click (kinda like youtube comments reply box).

Comment: Can you please tell us what the function is of what? So, give us a HTML structure and then tell us what everything does. I suppose that .post is a complete post of, say, images. Replybox contains all the replies and reply is just one reply?

Comment: Yes you're right. I just realized a fatal flaw in my logic. Since the user can open multiple reply boxes each new one duplicates ALL of the previous ones. I'm guessing I have to make one with a distinctive ID and then remove the id for the clones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.reply').click(function () {
    $(this).parent('.post').append($(".replybox").clone().show());
});
```

Comment: show() doesn't appear to be working. It duplicates fine if display is not set to none, but if it is show() isn't making it visible again...

Comment: Changed to .css('display','block') and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.reply').click(function () {
    var replybox = $(".replybox:hidden"); // take a reference of replybox
    $(this).parent('.post').append(replybox.clone().show());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".reply").click(function () {
 $(this).parent(".replybox").clone().hide().appendTo($(this).parents(".post")).fadeIn("slow") 
});​
```

But I'm still not sure what you want or what your HTML structure is, so probably this isn't what you want.